# Smallest Factor in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a program that takes the user input and then prints the list of factors.

I'm confused on how to print the smallest factors of my list.

Any suggestions?

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter integer: ");
    long num = input.nextLong();

    ArrayList<Long> list1 = new ArrayList<>(), list2 = new ArrayList<>();



    for(long i = 1; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
        if(num % i == 0) {
            list1.add(i);
            if(i != num/i) {
                list2.add(num/i);
            }
        }
    }

    int n1 = list1.size() - 1;
    int n2 = list2.size() - 1;

    for(int i = 0; i <= n1; i++) {
        System.out.println(list1.get(i));
    }

    for(int i = n2; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(list2.get(i));

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'smallest factors'? The smallest factor would always be 1, which would be at `list1.get(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current code, your may to want to implement some sort of search function to run your arraylists through. For starters you could use a basic linear search (Checking each item one at a time).

You need a place to store the current smallest factor (`int currSmallest`). Then you'll create a for-loop to iterate through each item (As you have done to print all the items) but instead check if that item is smaller than your `currSmallest` if so, replace `currSmallest` with the new factor.

If you'd like code, I can write it up for you, but I think you understand all the necessary components.